# Xamarin.iOS binding for a swift library

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am creating a binding for a swift library to be used in a xamarin project. When i consume the binding project in the ios project, I get the following error:

```
Dyld Error Message:
Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
Referenced from: 
/Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/73CDF7FB-D700-4F35- 
AB8B-DD7F7B134C1E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9FB74CDE-93C3- 
4EB7-9833- FA060281CE46/XXXXXXXX.iOS.app/Frameworks/MobiiiSDK.framework/MobiiiSDK
Reason: image not found
```

**I have added https://github.com/Flash3001/Xamarin.Swift to my project to reference swift libraries.**

**Have set both SmartLink and ForceLink to true**

**I have deleted the obj and bind folders in all projects. Did a clean and rebuild too.**

I would appreciate any help to fix this error.

Comment: Which project did you add the Swift libraries to? The Xamarin.iOS binding library project or the application project? (i.e. They need to be added to the application project)

Comment: @SushiHangover : I added to the application project.

Comment: @LibinJoseph Does `/Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/73CDF7FB-D700-4F35- 
AB8B-DD7F7B134C1E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9FB74CDE-93C3- 
4EB7-9833- FA060281CE46/XXXXXXXX.iOS.app/Frameworks/MobiiiSDK.framework/MobiiiSDK` file actually exist? It seems that particular framework is missing

Comment: @dalexsoto: I have just confirmed. Its there

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the direct answer to your question but can definitely take you in the right direction, here is the [Office UI Fabric](https://github.com/dalexsoto/xamarin-ui-fabric-ios) Xamarin.iOS Swift binding project that you can use as reference, it does not use (need) the [Xamarin.Swift](https://github.com/Flash3001/Xamarin.Swift) but uses a msbuild script that uses `swift-stdlib-tool` which is the tool that Xcode uses to determine what swift libraries need to be bundled with your application. The script [1] needs to be added to your final app .csproj as shown [here](https://github.com/dalexsoto/xamarin-ui-fabric-ios/blob/master/samples/OfficeUIFabricDemos/OfficeUIFabricDemos/OfficeUIFabricDemos.csproj#L147-L172).

In your particular case it seems that you are missing `MobiiiSDK.framework` from your bundle.

[1]: MSBuild script to bundle Swift libraries into your Xamarin iOS Application

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <_SwiftySwiftMasterAfterTargets>_CodesignNativeLibraries</_SwiftySwiftMasterAfterTargets>
    <_SwiftySwiftMasterDependsOnTargets>_SwiftySwiftCopySwiftDependencies</_SwiftySwiftMasterDependsOnTargets>
    <_XcodeToolChainRelativeToSdkRoot>/../../../../../Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/</_XcodeToolChainRelativeToSdkRoot>
    <_TargetPlatform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'iPhoneSimulator' ">iphonesimulator</_TargetPlatform>
    <_TargetPlatform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'iPhone' ">iphoneos</_TargetPlatform>
    <_SwiftySwiftRemoteMirror Condition=" '$(Configuration)' != 'Debug' "></_SwiftySwiftRemoteMirror>
    <_SwiftySwiftRemoteMirror Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">--resource-library libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib</_SwiftySwiftRemoteMirror>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="_SwiftySwiftMasterTarget" Condition="'$(_SwiftySwiftMasterDependsOnTargets)'!=''" AfterTargets="$(_SwiftySwiftMasterAfterTargets)" DependsOnTargets="$(_SwiftySwiftMasterDependsOnTargets);_DetectSigningIdentity" />
  <Target Name="_SwiftySwiftCopySwiftDependencies" Condition="!Exists('$(_AppBundlePath)Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib')">
    <Message Text="Copying Swift Frameworks dependencies for $(_NativeExecutable) to the $(_AppBundlePath)Frameworks folder." />
    <Exec Condition="'$(_CodeSigningKey)' != ''" SessionId="$(BuildSessionId)" Command="$(_SdkRoot)$(_XcodeToolChainRelativeToSdkRoot)usr/bin/swift-stdlib-tool --copy --verbose --sign '$(_CodeSigningKey)' --scan-executable '$(_NativeExecutable)' --scan-folder '$(_AppBundlePath)Frameworks/' --scan-folder '$(_AppBundlePath)PlugIns/' --platform '$(_TargetPlatform)' --toolchain '$(_SdkRoot)$(_XcodeToolChainRelativeToSdkRoot)' --destination '$(_AppBundlePath)Frameworks/' $(_SwiftySwiftRemoteMirror) --unsigned-destination '$(DeviceSpecificIntermediateOutputPath)/SwiftSupport' --strip-bitcode --strip-bitcode-tool '$(_SdkRoot)$(_XcodeToolChainRelativeToSdkRoot)usr/bin/bitcode_strip' --emit-dependency-info '$(DeviceSpecificIntermediateOutputPath)/SwiftStdLibToolInputDependencies.dep'" />
    <Exec Condition="'$(_CodeSigningKey)' == ''" SessionId="$(BuildSessionId)" Command="$(_SdkRoot)$(_XcodeToolChainRelativeToSdkRoot)usr/bin/swift-stdlib-tool --copy --verbose                             --scan-executable '$(_NativeExecutable)' --scan-folder '$(_AppBundlePath)Frameworks/' --scan-folder '$(_AppBundlePath)PlugIns/' --platform '$(_TargetPlatform)' --toolchain '$(_SdkRoot)$(_XcodeToolChainRelativeToSdkRoot)' --destination '$(_AppBundlePath)Frameworks/' $(_SwiftySwiftRemoteMirror) --unsigned-destination '$(DeviceSpecificIntermediateOutputPath)/SwiftSupport' --strip-bitcode --strip-bitcode-tool '$(_SdkRoot)$(_XcodeToolChainRelativeToSdkRoot)usr/bin/bitcode_strip' --emit-dependency-info '$(DeviceSpecificIntermediateOutputPath)/SwiftStdLibToolInputDependencies.dep'" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="_SwiftySwiftCopySwiftSupport" Condition="'$(ArchiveOnBuild)'=='true'" AfterTargets="Archive">
    <Message Text="Copying SwiftSupport folder from $(DeviceSpecificIntermediateOutputPath)/SwiftSupport to $(ArchiveDir)/SwiftSupport folder." />
    <Ditto
        SessionId="$(BuildSessionId)"
        Condition="'$(IsMacEnabled)' == 'true'"
        ToolExe="$(DittoExe)"
        ToolPath="$(DittoPath)"
        Source="$(DeviceSpecificIntermediateOutputPath)/SwiftSupport"
        Destination="$(ArchiveDir)/SwiftSupport" />
  </Target>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried it, and I am still getting the same error. is there anything else that I can look into to get some hints on what might be causing it?

Comment: My apologies. The error was because the framework that I was using was not configured for simulator(was not fat library).

Comment: @LibinJoseph is it required to generate fat library for simulator even support is not required?